# Downgrade the Service Fabric Application version

Tags: azure, deployment, upgrade, downgrade

When I'm deploying the Service Fabric Application with new version, the complete application is getting replaced with new version in service fabric cluster. And it is working fine as expected in upgrade scenario. But, When I deploy the application with downgraded version, application is not getting replaced rather it is again creating an application with older version.

After the application deployment, I have two different versions of same application in service fabric cluster.

How we can downgrade the application to older version with application deployment. Does we need to change settings/parameters for cluster or in power shell command.
[Service Fabric cluster with two versions after deployment of older version image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yebUD.png)

Thanks.

Comment: I have a service fabric application in sf cluster with version say 1.0.1. And when I deploy application with 1.0.0 in cluster it shown just few minutes as application with 1.0.0 version in deployed service packages section then later it showing as 1.0.1. Between this, there were two actions were heppened, Upgrade state(Upgrade Progress section) as "RollingForwardPending" then after some time RollingBackInProgress. May I know what is the reason of the its getting back to initial version & how can I make the application to stick to the version which I deployed last(here it is 1.0.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a view of the Service Fabric Image store, which shows the current versions available, below this you should be able to see the actual version that is being used within the cluster, see below, versions 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 are currently in the image store but version 1.0.0 is the version being used.

[image]

You can confirm this by looking at your nodes as well.

[image]

EDIT:

To remove the unwanted versions from the cluster run the following in PowerShell, obvious replace with your application name and version.

```
> Unregister-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationTypeName DowngradeDemoType -ApplicationTypeVersion 1.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks jimpaine, but I don't want to see the application with the entry remained in service fabric cluster. Cant we remove the entry from the cluster. Because if I install the applications with 3/4 older versions then I will have multiple entries. So, I just want to maintain active version entry only. Does we have any powerahell command to remove these unused application version entries.

Comment: Upgrade/downgrade works if cluster doesnot has any health issues then upgrade/downgrade will work fine.